# get the last completed task date in case

Tags: apex, trigger, validation, case-object

i am new in salesforce development.
we have a change request for my company implementation.

in Case object, i need 1 custom field to save the last 'completed' task date.

from that custom field, i need to create workflow to notify the case owner and support manager about case that have no open task for several day and the case status still not 'Closed'.

i confused to fill the custom field on case to store the last 'completed' task date(it last modified).

Comment: I think u need to use escalation riles for that. Not sure why u need the extra date field

Comment: i need custom field to create a workflow to compare today date with that custom date field. if more than 3 day and case status is not closed. it will send email to support manager.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is to use Escalation Rules.

Creating Escalation rules: http://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_escrules.htm

RTFM Escalation Rules: http://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/creating_escalation_rules.htm

What you are asking for is basic behavior within SF, no need for extra fields IMO.

Comment: hi Saariko,i have tried Escalation rule too. but it can't work as i want. i need to know the latest completed task modified date. to next create a notif to service manager that there is a case that the status still not Closed for several days after task that assign to the case have completed. the problem is i cannot get the date of completed task.

Comment: try to add a rollup summary field on the account. that takes that date.